# Display query post based on two orderby value in wordpress

Tags: meta-query, menu-order, popular-posts

I have been trying to display popular posts (based on view counts) and fetching them randomly using array in `orderby` but it doesn't seem to be working. The reason I want them to display randomly is because I don't want the same post to be displayed repeatedly to both new & repeated visitors as the views count increases naturally.

Here is the code I tried:

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category'          => 'comedy',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  4,
        'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby'           => array ('meta_value_num', 'rand'),   //this is the one I want both rand & meta_value_num to retrieve
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    ) 
);

while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
    the_permalink();
    the_title();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
        the_permalink(' ');the_title();
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;
    the_excerpt(); // echo the excerpt
endwhile;
```

Everything is working except that it doesn't fetch randomly. The same post are always shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be very easy for you to get the top 25 based on view count and then get a random selection of 4 from that list.

Below is an easy to test query but you would want to replace with just your `post_views_count` query and remove any `rand` orderby.

```
// get top 25
$posts = get_posts( array (
    'post_type'      => array ( 'post' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
) );

// randomize the top 25
shuffle( $posts );

// pull to first 4 items
$posts = array_slice( $posts, 0, 4 );

// show the results
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $posts as $post_id ) {
    echo get_the_title( $post_id ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Using your query:

```
// query the top posts
$popularpost = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category'          => 'comedy',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  25, // top 25
        'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby'           => array ('meta_value_num'),
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    )
);

// randomize the items
shuffle($popularpost->posts);

// limit the the number of posts
$popularpost->posts = array_slice( $popularpost->posts, 4); // random 4 posts

// output
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
    the_permalink();
    the_title();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
        the_permalink(' ');the_title();
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;
    the_excerpt(); // echo the excerpt
endwhile;
```

Comment: Looks like this code is working but it totally breaks my site..  can you please update the code? thanks

Comment: @JayBro can you tell me what breaks?

Comment: I'm using this one in template page where i use shortcode (plugin) to show the latest post .. And the above code is for suggesting (suggestted reading) at the top of the page... When I put this code, it totally breaks the post from shortcodes..

Comment: It shouldn't have had problem, but I'm not sure it's fetching the comments loop.

Comment: I updated to use your meta and post type. Random 4 from the top 25 posts.

Comment: Amazing!! it's working perfect.. Thanks for helping out.. Anyway, do you recommend using query or get_posts that may have possible page load problem?